# Alt+F2 not working properly

Tags: gnome, 18.04

While trying to restart the gnome shell, I entered r after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and it responded with a message of 'restarting' but nothing happened. I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: Say more about 'nothing' happened.  Is the window system unresponsive?  E.g. can you move a window?

Comment: Did this happen once or is it a regular incident?

Comment: can you run the command from terminal and see what comes out? it's probably saying you don't have permission

Comment: Yes, the window system is unresponsive. It does nothing and I can carry on to do whatever task I was doing prior to it.

Comment: Ok, I tried restarting gnome using the command line and it's working fine.

Comment: @NikhilShrivastava Does Alt+F2 work now?

Comment: No, it has starting to act funny actually. I just tried it three times, the first time it just increased the 'warmness/yellowness' of my night light and the other two times it did nothing.