# The icon between settings and lock-screen in Gnome3 is acting abnormally?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

Whenever I click on that 'lock' icon, it just freezes my screen for a few moments then everything gets back to normal. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and I vaguely remember that in 16.04 it used to log me out.

Comment: But I am not using it on a touchscreen so why does it just freeze my screen?

Comment: I don't get it, it has nothing to do with touchscreens. It's freezing the screen probably due to some deeper problems with your system (you are facing [other issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066653/altf2-not-working-properly) too).